# Firmware Update for Windows 8.1 Pro Surface through Windows Update Fails

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, microsoft-surface

I am trying to update to the latest version of the firmware on my Windows 8.1 Pro Surface. The firmware update is presented through Windows Update.

I click on the "Install and Restart" button, but after the computer finishes rebooting, Windows Update shows the firmware update still pending.

Answer (score 1):

Install all the other Windows Updates first, then do the firmware update last. There appears to be some sort of dependency involved.